# Doctrine2 YML Mapping on Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, mapping, yaml, bidirectional

I am starting with Symfony2, and so do I with Doctrine2.

I want to make an entity bidirectional, but I don't know what I am doing wrong. Here is my two .orm.yml files :

Categorie.orm.yml :

```
MY\SUPERBundle\Entity\Categorie:
  type: entity
  fields:
    id:
      id: true
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
    nomCategorie:
      type: text
      nullable: true
      column: NomCategorie
  oneToMany:
    SousCategories:
      targetEntity: MY\SUPERBundle\Entity\SousCategorie
      mappedBy: Categorie
```

SousCategorie.orm.yml :

```
MY\SUPERBundle\Entity\SousCategorie:
  type: entity
  fields:
    id:
      id: true
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
    nomSousCategorie:
      type: text
      nullable: true
      column: NomSousCategorie
  manyToOne:
    Categorie:
      targetEntity: MY\SUPERBundle\Entity\Categorie
      inversedBy: SousCategories
      joinColumns:
        categorie_id:
          referencedColumnName: id
          nullable: false
```

When I want to run the command :

```
doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

I am getting this error :

```
 [ReflectionException]
  Property MY\SUPERBundle\Entity\Categorie::$SousCategories does not exist
```

If you guys have any hint on what I am doing wrong, I would be very grateful.

Thanks !

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the solution but your property "SousCategories" should not be capitalized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you really have a property named "SousCategories" under your "Categorie" class?
Would be nice if you could add your entity class in your first post.

BTW, if it's a property, it shouldn't begin with an uppercase letter.

Comment: That is right. I did not added a property named "SousCategories" under my "Categorie" class. What should be the name of it ? I mean, does a private @sousCategories is good enough ?

Comment: Yes a private `sousCategories` class property with accessors should be enough :)